# Significance of resource parameter in Nelmiobundles API doc parameter

Tags: rest, annotations, symfony-2.3, api-doc, nelmioapidocbundle

What is the significance of resource parameter in NelmioBundle's APIDoc annotation?

It accepts boolean value (https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/the-apidoc-annotation.html)

Can someone explain the exact use case to use true / false value against this parameter?

Thanks in advance.